# tidyr::unite fails when df has custom class

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm trying to use `tidyr::unite` on a dataframe that has a custom class applied from a package I'm developing. As an example, trying to unite 2 columns of the `iris` dataset

```
data(iris)
class(iris) <- append(class(iris), "new_class")

iris_unite <- tidyr::unite(iris, col = "example", c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"))
```

Fails with

```
Error: `x` must be a vector, not a `data.frame/new_class` object.
```

If you omit the line assigning the custom class, then the code works fine.

I'd expect `unite` to still work as expected, as the data frame still has the `data.frame` class applied, so I'd assume this would dispatch to `unite.data.frame`.

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: You should put your most specific class first. It should work with `class(iris) <- class(iris) <- c("new_class", "data.frame")` rather than the other way around.

Comment: So simple. Thanks @MrFlick!